# SSH into Azure web-app container running with non root user

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssh, azure-web-app-service

I am running an Elastic and Kibana service within a container using an Azure Web app container service. I was keen on checking the SSH connectivity for this container using Azures Web SSH console feature. Followed the microsoft documentation for SSH into custom containers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh which shows the example of running the container as default root user.

My issue is Elasticsearch process does not run as a root user so I had to make the sshd process run as an elastic user. I was able to get the `sshd` process running which accepts the SSH connection from my host however the credentials I am setting in the docker file (elasticsearch:Docker!) are throwing Access Denied error.Any idea where i am going wrong here?

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:jre-alpine

ARG ek_version=6.5.4

RUN apk add --quiet --no-progress --no-cache nodejs wget \
 && adduser -D elasticsearch \
 && apk add openssh \
 && echo "elasticsearch:Docker!" | chpasswd
 
# Copy the sshd_config file to the /etc/ssh/ directory

COPY startup.sh /home/elasticsearch/
RUN chmod +x /home/elasticsearch/startup.sh && \
    chown elasticsearch /home/elasticsearch/startup.sh

COPY sshd_config /home/elasticsearch/

USER elasticsearch

WORKDIR /home/elasticsearch

ENV ES_TMPDIR=/home/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.tmp ES_DATADIR=/home/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/data

RUN wget -q -O - https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss-${ek_version}.tar.gz \
 |  tar -zx \
 && mv elasticsearch-${ek_version} elasticsearch \
 && mkdir -p ${ES_TMPDIR} ${ES_DATADIR} \
 && wget -q -O - https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-oss-${ek_version}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
 |  tar -zx \
 && mv kibana-${ek_version}-linux-x86_64 kibana \
 && rm -f kibana/node/bin/node kibana/node/bin/npm \
 && ln -s $(which node) kibana/node/bin/node \
 && ln -s $(which npm) kibana/node/bin/npm

EXPOSE 9200 5601 2222

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/elasticsearch/startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh

# Generating hostkey 
ssh-keygen -f /home/elasticsearch/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa

# starting sshd process
echo "Starting SSHD"
/usr/sbin/sshd -f sshd_config

# Staring the ES stack
echo "Starting ES"
sh elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -E http.host=0.0.0.0 & kibana/bin/kibana --host 0.0.0.0
```

sshd_config file

```
Port            2222
HostKey /home/elasticsearch/ssh_host_rsa_key
PidFile /home/elasticsearch/sshd.pid
ListenAddress       0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime      180
X11Forwarding       yes
Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes         yes
SyslogFacility      DAEMON
PasswordAuthentication  yes
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin     yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Error i am getting
[image]

Comment: Where do you ssh to the container?

Answer (score -1):

Please check and verify that your docker image supports SSH. It would appear that you have done everything correctly so one of the final troubleshooting steps left as this point is to verify that your image supports SSH to begin with.